# Can't Get Phaser To Work

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

For the past few days, I have been unable to get phaser to work: just trying to test a hello world program. I've followed the directions on phaser's site exactly, and it still isn't working for me.

I am using node.js.

Here is index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
     <title>Hello World</title>

     <style>
        #game_div {
        width: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 50px;
      }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="phaser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="game_div"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is main.js:

```
/*jslint node: true */
"use strict";
var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.AUTO, 'game_div');

var main_state = {

    preload: function () {
        game.load.image('hello', 'assets/hello.png');
    },

    create: function () {
        this.hello_sprite = game.add.sprite(200, 245, 'hello');
    },

    update: function () {
        this.hello_sprite.angle += 1;
    }
}

game.state.add('main', main_state);
game.state.start('main');
```

The error it gives me is:

> 'Phaser' was used before it was defined.
>   var game = new Phaser.Game(400, 490, Phaser.AUTO, 'game_div');

I've really tried looking for solutions to this, but I can't find anything wrong. I'm pretty new to JavaScript and phaser.

Comment: What happens when you load index.html? Does the console say anything?

Comment: the console reads:    Phaser v2.0.2 - WebGL - WebAudio     http://phaser.io    ♥♥♥  phaser.min.js:7
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at file:///C:/Users/Demx/Desktop/Programming/Testing/assets/hello.png may not be loaded. phaser.min.js:4

Comment: Sounds like you need to run it over a webserver

Comment: If you post your question on the official Phaser forum you'll surely get an answer: http://www.html5gamedevs.com/forum/14-phaser/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The SecurityError above points to the root of the problem: You're opening the file directly in your browser, under which you've no permissions to access local files like this. It needs to be served via a web server. If you need any help with this we cover it in the Getting Started guide on the web site.

Answer (score 0):

in the google chrome shortcut that reads like `chrome.exe` try adding `--allow-file-access-from-files` then open the browser and load the webpage for linux it will be `/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U --allow-file-access-from-files` it worked for me the image was loaded even when running locally

Comment: Had the same problem as OP and your sollution is not working for me.